# CSS hover on div doesn't affect anchor that sits inside?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
      .btn{
           display: inline-block;
           padding: 15px 10px;
           background: gray;
       }
      .btn:hover{
             background:lightgray;
             color:red;
      }
</style>

<div class="btn"> 
   text
</div>
```

works nicely. However if we have that:

```
<div class="btn"> 
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

it wouldn't work exactly as the first one. The anchor's text wouldn't be affected. Okay what if we add to the CSS:

```
.btn a:hover{
    background:lightgray;
   color:red;
 }
```

That will work, but only if you hover exactly on the anchor, but still hover on the div rectangle wouldn't affect the anchor's text.

How can I tweak that without any javascript, so both rectangles acted identically?

http://jsfiddle.net/vaNJD/

UPD: adding `!important` keyword wouldn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because all web browsers set a default `color` (and `text-decoration`) for `a` elements, you need a [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/) selector to override the default.  Try this instead:

```
.btn:hover, .btn:hover a {
    background:lightgray;
    color:red;
}
```

If you really want the two boxes to be identical, you would also need to override the un-hovered button as well:

```
.btn a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It may also be worth pointing out that IE6 only supports the `:hover` pseudo-class on `a` elements.  You may want to work around this by setting the `a` to `display: block` and adding the background color there.

You can accomplish the same effect by getting rid of the container and applying the `.btn` class directly to the `a` element.  See the third box in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/vaNJD/5/

Comment: He would have to reset the brower's default color/text-decoration settings as well. `.btn a { text-decoration:none; color:black; }`

Comment: I read this question as being more about `:hover` than about styling links in general, but your point is valid, so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
     .btn:hover{
             background:lightgray;
             color:red;
      }
      .btn:hover a{
        color: red;
      }
```

Comment: +1, because `<a>` doesn't inherit `color` styling from it's parents

Comment: @mdmullinax, color is inherited (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html).  The issue is specificity, because the browser sets a default color for `a` elements.

Comment: agreed, I separated because it wasn't clear that he wanted the background set.

Comment: @Michael color is inherited from more generic anchor styling rules, but `<a>` does not inherit color information from parent elements such as `<p>`, `<div>`, or `<body>`

Comment: It doesn't "inherit" the color because there's already a more specific color rule set by the browser.  If the browser would also set a default color for `p`, paragraphs also wouldn't inherit their parent's color.  This is because of specificity, not because inheritance doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe this is more clear: Links do inherit color from their parents, but this color doesn't show up because the browser's default link color (which is tied to a more specific selector) overrides the inherited color.  In practice it's the same thing, but it isn't true to say that `a` doesn't inherit color.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I guess that was my point, the default browser styling will prevent color styling on an anchor to inherit from the parent, but yeah, the way I worded it was wrong

Answer (score 1):

[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/vaNJD/1/)

```
.btn:hover a{
    color:red;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
.btn:hover,
.btn:hover a{
    background:lightgray;
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vaNJD/4/

Answer (score 0):

I found one way in which you should set height for div tag and use it again for anchor tag and set anchor's display properties as block
for example

```
<style>
.divest
{
height:120px;
}
.divest a
{
display:block;
height:120px;
}
</style>
<div class="divest"><a href="#">here is hyperlink text</a></div>
```